# Relations of injective and surjective in adjoint opeerators.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, orthogonality, adjoint-operators

I'm trying to solve the converse of following excercise
[image: Excerise 9 chapter 4]

where E and F are Banach Space, $E^*$ and $F^*$ are the dual space, $S(E,F)$ is the set of surjective linear and bounded maps and $I(E,F)$ is the set of the linear bounded operators that has closed image.

First, I tried with orthogonality relations and have this
$$
\overline{R(T)} =\, ^\perp\ker(T^*) =\, ^\perp\{0\} = F.
$$
But I'm not sure how prove that the image is closed.

Also, I was reading the solution from the book but I'm confused, I suppose that tries to prove that is a open map and futhermore a surjective map.

[image: solution of excerise]

The book is: Analyse Fonctionnelle et théorie des opérateurs.

Any suggestion or hint would be appreciate

Comment: In $\impliedby$ the image is closed  by Banach's Closed Range Theorem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_range_theorem

Comment: You say "$I(E,F)$ is the set of linear bounded operators with closed image". This can't be right, as the adjoint of 0 is 0, which has closed image, but 0 is not surjective unless $F=0$. Is the question actually about the fact that $T$ is surjective iff $T^*$ is an isomorphism to its image?